# Calculating statistics from a double array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of double values. I would like to calculate a max and average from all of the values in that array.

Currently I just iterate trough the array and calculate the numbers, and everything works fine. But it feels odd to me, that I have to implement such a basic methods. I was looking in Java API if there is a method that can do something like that, but I could not find any... Am I missing something?

I've searched here, but I only found a bunch of examples, where they implement it the same way I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a library such as [Apache commons math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/). Use `StatUtils` which has a bunch of useful static methods to achieve just what you need.

Just download the library and add it to your project dependencies.

Here is an example of usage of this library:

```
// Just building an array with double values
int size = 10;
double measurements[] = new double[size];

for (int i = 0; i < measurements.length; i++)
{
    measurements[i] = i;
}

// Using the Apache functions
double myAverage = StatUtils.mean (measurements);
double myMax = StatUtils.max (measurements);
```

Comment: This library is very useful! It took me less than 5 minutes to add new maven dependency and test your code. I knew I shouldn't have to implement this on my own. StatUtils really is handy piece of tool! :)

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 introduces several primitive streams (double, long, int) that have a statistics facility. It looks like:

```
double[] array = {1, 2, 3, 5, 3};
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(array).summaryStatistics();
System.out.println(stats.getMax());
System.out.println(stats.getAverage());
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you describe is so simple that in most cases there is no cause for a general library to provide it, especially since a lot of the time there are all sorts of options such as whether you also want the min, max, etc all worked out at the same time or not.

Having said that though Java 8 is bringing in a whole new collections processing API which would (among a lot of other very powerful things) allow you to do just that.

For more information see:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-streams-api-preview

http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/